# Не могу скачать изменения с gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Буду краток :  Я попытался загрузить с моего репозитория на gitlab то, что я разрабатывал раннее . Скачались изменения, но старые . Я хз с чем это связанно . Я пытался загрузить эти изменения обратно, но фиг там плавал . Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: думаю нужно чуток почитать мат часть. https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git

Comment: Что мне это даст ? Я не могу загрузить изменения с удалённого репозитория в локальный . Я пробывал и pull и fetch . Извините если прозвучало грубо

Comment: Попробуйте git clone .... И убедитесь что нужные вам файлы имеются в репозитории.

Comment: Ну как тут помочь. Мы хз что случилось. Попробуй что-нибудь ещё.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за всё . Вообщем я скачал архив с репом и всё залил в папку . Перед этим я всё удалил . 
Сделал: git init , git remote add origin , git pull origin , git branch --track master origin/master , git checkout -b dev , git branch --track dev origin/dev , git pull origin